# Is it possible to remove voice search for edits in Android

Tags: android

I have a requirement to suppress voice recognition button in Android SoftKeyboard.

During my research I found the setInputMethodAndSubType which has mode parameter. But I cannot locate how it can be used.

Any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was incorrect. The correct flag was android:inputType. If you set this flag to textUri on your EditText it will make the voice recognition button not appear.

```
android:inputType="textUri"
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggest, But it is not working at all.